# SQL Workbench to reverse engineer database - making too many connections

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, erd

I have a database created, code provided here. Foreign Keys are defined after creation with Alter Table commands.

When reverse engineering and looking at the EER diagram, some of the tables are connected by multiple relationship lines - is there a way to simply change the connection to one line depicting 1-1, 1-M relationship?

EER is linked at bottom.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS DasBus;

CREATE DATABASE DasBus;
use DasBus;

BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE Path (
  PATH_NUM VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  START_POINT VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  END_POINT VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  INTER DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
  TOT_DURATION TIME NOT NULL,
  PATH_DELAY_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  BUS_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PATH_STOP_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  SCHED_NUM VARCHAR(10) not null
);

CREATE TABLE Path_Delay (
  PATH_DELAY_NUM VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  ISDELAYED BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PATH_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  DELAY_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Delay (
  DELAY_NUM VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  DELAY_TIME INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PATH_DELAY_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Path_Stop (
  PATH_STOP_NUM VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  PATH_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  STOP_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  TIMEBETWEEN INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE BusStop (
  STOP_NUM VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  STOP_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  ISACTIVE BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  STOPCONDITION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PATH_STOP_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  SCHED_NUM VARCHAR(10) not null
);

CREATE TABLE BusSchedule (
  SCHED_NUM VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  INTER TIME NOT NULL,
  START_TIME TIME NOT NULL,
  END_TIME TIME NOT NULL,
  PATH_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  STOP_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Bus (
  BUS_NUM VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  BUS_CAPACITY INTEGER(4),
  DRIVER_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PATH_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Driver (
  DRIVER_NUM VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  DRIVER_LNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  DRIVER_FNAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  DRIVER_STREET VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  DRIVER_CITY VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  DRIVER_ZIP CHAR(6),
  DRIVER_PHONE VARCHAR(15),
  BUS_NUM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

<p>ALTER TABLE PATH ADD CONSTRAINT Path1 FOREIGN KEY (BUS_NUM) REFERENCES Bus(BUS_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE PATH ADD CONSTRAINT Path2 FOREIGN KEY (PATH_DELAY_NUM) REFERENCES Path_Delay (PATH_DELAY_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE PATH ADD CONSTRAINT Path3 FOREIGN KEY (PATH_STOP_NUM) REFERENCES Path_Stop(PATH_STOP_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE PATH ADD CONSTRAINT Path4 FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NUM) REFERENCES BusSchedule(SCHED_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE Path_Delay ADD CONSTRAINT Path_Delay1 FOREIGN KEY (PATH_NUM) REFERENCES Path(PATH_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE Path_Delay ADD CONSTRAINT Path_Delay2 FOREIGN KEY (DELAY_NUM) REFERENCES Delay(DELAY_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE DELAY ADD CONSTRAINT Delay1 FOREIGN KEY (PATH_DELAY_NUM) REFERENCES Path_Delay(PATH_DELAY_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE BusStop ADD CONSTRAINT BusStop1 FOREIGN KEY (PATH_STOP_NUM) REFERENCES Path_Stop(PATH_STOP_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE BusStop ADD CONSTRAINT BusStop2 FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NUM) REFERENCES BusSchedule(SCHED_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE BUS ADD CONSTRAINT Bus1 FOREIGN KEY (DRIVER_NUM) REFERENCES Driver(DRIVER_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE BUS ADD CONSTRAINT Bus2 FOREIGN KEY (PATH_NUM) REFERENCES Path(PATH_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE DRIVER ADD CONSTRAINT Driver1 FOREIGN KEY (BUS_NUM) REFERENCES Bus(BUS_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE Path_Stop ADD CONSTRAINT Path_Stop1 FOREIGN KEY (PATH_NUM) REFERENCES Path(PATH_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE Path_Stop ADD CONSTRAINT Path_Stop2 FOREIGN KEY (STOP_NUM) REFERENCES BusStop(STOP_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE BusSchedule ADD CONSTRAINT BusSchedule1 FOREIGN KEY (STOP_NUM) REFERENCES BusStop (STOP_NUM);
<p>ALTER TABLE BusSchedule ADD CONSTRAINT BusSchedule2 FOREIGN KEY (PATH_NUM) REFERENCES Path (PATH_NUM);
```

EER diagram:

[image]

Comment: That diagram is not an ERD, it's a table diagram. Also, FK constraints are not ER relationships. Relationships are represented by two or more entity keys in a table, e.g. `(BUS_NUM, DRIVER_NUM)` in the `bus` table. FK constraints enforce logical domains, they're not used to relate things in the ER model.

Answer (score 0):

The lines connecting your tables are derived from the foreign keys defined on your tables. If you would like to reduce their number, then you need to reduce the number of foreign keys.

Since all your tables are connected by at least 2 lines, I would say you do not fully understand foreign keys and setting up relationships in general. Let's take `bus` and `driver` tables as an example.

The foreign keys cross reference the 2 tables. You probably wanted to express an `n:m` relationship this way, saying that a single driver may drive multiple buses, but a single bus may be driven by multiple drivers.

The right way to implement such a relationship is to introduce a 3rd table (let's call it `bus_drivers`) that contains the primary keys from the `bus` and `drivers` tables at the minimum. Such a table is called [associative table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

You need to revisit all your foreign keys and tables and modify them until the generated diagram is in line with your expectations. You may have to add quite a few associative tables if you have so many `n:m` relationships.

After the initial mapping of relationships based on foreign keys you can modify the visibility and cardinality of the relationships in mysql workbench's [relationship editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-editor.html).

Comment: MySQL Workbench even automaticially creates the associative table when you use the n:m tool.